# Recursive mapped types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I don't know if this is possible but I'm wondering if you can create recursively mapped types. I don't know if that makes sense so let me try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm creating an excel parser that takes in workbook and returns a type `T`. One of the things I want to do is create a mapped typed that maps every key to a `string` which will correspond to an excel cell reference in the form of a string (e.g. `'A5'`).

I can map every key to a string like so:

```
{[P in keyof T]: string}
```

but this maps complex types (objects and arrays) to strings too but I'd actually like to map the keys of those complex values to a string too.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I'm starting to think it's not possible because something like [this would need to be implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424).

Comment: Yes, you need mapped conditional types.  You might want to go to the GitHub issue and give it a  so they know more people want it...

Answer (score 0):

you couldn t before but you can now from Typescript 4.1 version. conditional recursive types are now supported